# What is the "**params" syntax in a Python method definition?

Tags: python, syntax

So I am trying out the new python code for the google app engine search library and I came across a weird syntax.  This was:

```
cls_createDocument(**params)
```

where params was a dictionary.

The function this refers to is:

```
    @classmethod
  def _createDocument(
      cls, pid=None, category=None, name=None, description=None,
      category_name=None, price=None, **params)
```

My questions is, what does the **params signify and what does that do to the object?

Thanks!
Jon

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider a function with default arguments:

```
def func(foo=3):
    print(foo)
```

The structure of the arguments is (in principle) very similar to a dictionary.  The function foo has (essentially) a dictionary of default arguments (in this case `{'foo':3}`).  Now, lets say that you don't want to use the keyword in the function call, but you want to use a dictionary instead -- then you can call `foo` as:

```
d = {"foo":8}
func(**d)
```

This allows you to dynamically change what arguments you are passing to the function `func`.

This become a little more interesting if you try the following:

```
d = {"foo":8, "bar":12}
func(**d)
```

This doesn't work (it is equivalent to `foo(foo=8, bar=12)`, but since `bar` isn't a valid argument, it fails).

You can get around that problem by giving those extra arguments a place to go inside the definition of `foo`.

```
def func( foo=3, **kwargs ):
    print(foo,kwargs)
```

Now, try:

```
d = {"foo":8, "bar":12}
func(**d)  #prints (8, {'bar':12})
```

All the extra keyword arguments go into the kwargs dictionary inside the function.

This can also be called as:

```
func(foo=8, bar=12)
```

with the same result.

This is often useful if funcA calls funcB and you want funcA to accept all of the keywords of funcB (plus a few extra) which is a very common thing when dealing with classes and inheritance:

```
def funcA(newkey=None,**kwargs): 
    funcB(**kwargs)
```

Finally, here is a [link to the documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments)

Comment: Thank you so much, especially for the link to the documentation.  I have "dabbled" in python but have mostly programmed in java.  Is there any book you would recommend I read?

Comment: The docs and tutorial ( http://docs.python.org/tutorial/ ) are quite nice.  I never actually read any books ... Python reads pretty nicely for the basic stuff.  The more complicated stuff I picked up as I went along.

Answer (score 3):

The **params parameter represents all the keyword arguments passed to the function as a dictionary.